# Mean and Variance Statistics

Tags: statistics, education

$X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n$ ~ i.i.d $U[0,1]$

a) Find the mean and variance of $lnX_1$.

b) Let $0\le  a \lt b$.
Find the $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(a \le (X_1,X_2, \dots ,X_n)^{(n^ -0.5)}*e^{ ( n^{0.5})}\le b)$
in terms of $a$ and $b$.

For part a since it is a uniform distribution I know that it will be equal to $1 \times (\frac{1}{(1-0)}) \times ln(1) = 0$. I tried to integrate this from $0$ to $1$ multiplying $x$ in order to find the expected value, but it is giving me the answer $0$. Same goes for variance.

For part $b$, I am stuck completely.

Help needed. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the part (a) mean $\frac{1}{1-0} \int_0^1 x \ln(x) \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: What does the notation mean in the second part...looks like a multi-dimensional point raised to the n-0.5 power..what do you do with that?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 it is e^n^ -0.5

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

mean of $\ln X_{1}$:

$\mathbb{E}\ln X_{1}=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\ln xdx=-1-\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\left(\varepsilon\ln\varepsilon-\varepsilon\right)=-1$.

Here $x\ln x-x$ is the antiderivative of $\ln x$ and [$\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\varepsilon\ln\varepsilon=0$](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWTfgehRxzU).

Note that $\ln X_{1}$ only takes negative values on interval $(0,1]$ and is not defined on $0$.

variance of $\ln X_{1}$:

$\mathbb{E}\ln^{2}X_{1}=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\ln^{2}xdx=2-\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\left(\varepsilon\ln^{2}\varepsilon-2\varepsilon\ln\varepsilon+2\varepsilon\right)=2$.

Here $x\ln^{2}x-2x\ln x+2x$ is the antiderivative of $\ln^{2}x$
and $\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\varepsilon\ln^{2}\varepsilon=0$.

This leads to $\text{Var}\left(\ln X_{1}\right)=\mathbb{E}\ln^{2}X_{1}-\left(\mathbb{E}\ln X_{1}\right)^{2}=2-(-1)^{2}=2-1=1$.

Comment: which are the mean and variance you would get if you use $-\ln X_1 \sim \rm{Exp}(1)$

Comment: @Henry I suspect that 9 years ago I did not think about that, because nowadays I don't understand why I did not mention it.